# Преобразование из String в массив байтов и обратно

Tags: java, кодировка, потоки-данных

Написал на Java следующую последовательность действий:

1. Получаю из строки с кириллицей массив байтов

   ```
   byte[] bytes="новая строка".getBytes();
   ```
2. Получается следующий массив:

   `[-19, -18, -30, -32, -1, 32, -15, -14, -16, -18, -22, -32]`
3. Передаю его на вход классу `ByteArrayOutputStream`

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   baos.write(bytes);
   ```
4. Выполняю обратное преобразование из массива байтов в строку

   ```
   System.out.println(baos.toString());
   ```
5. Программа выводит в консоль текст `новая строка`

Вопрос: так как кириллица в юникоде имеет кодепойнты, превышающие 1 тысячу (кодепойнт буквы `А`, к примеру, равен 1040), а байт в Java может принимать значения от -128 до 127, следовательно при попытке преобразовать строку в массив типа `byte` должна происходить потеря информации, как следствие - при вызове метода `toString()` строка должна восстановиться некорректно. Но этого не произошло. В чем тут причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не юникод. [String.getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes())  использует кодировку по-умолчанию платформы:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **platform's default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array.

Кодировка по-умолчанию задается настройками Java, ее можно проверить с помощью:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

Для получения байтов в юникоде, задайте кодировку явно:

```
byte[] bytes="новая строка".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Получится больше 12 байтов.

**Обновление по вопросам в комментарии:**

> Разве UTF-8 выдает байты, эквивалентные юникодовскому представлению?

У юникода бывают [разные представления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). UTF-8 — одно из них.

> Я знаю, что char выдает кодепойнты юникода. Если вывести System.out.println((byte)'н'), то это будет равно 61.

Здесь можно посмотреть как строчная кириллическая «н» представляется в разных кодировках: https://unicode-table.com/en/043D/

> **UTF-8:**
> Десятичное значение: 53437
> Байты: 208 189
>
> **UTF-16BE:**
> Десятичное значение: 1085
> Байты: 4 61

Для char в Java, согласно спецификации ([§3.1 Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)) используется кодировка UTF-16. Это тоже двухбайтовая кодировка. Соответственно, когда Вы приводите `char` к `byte` Вы получаете младший байт в этой кодировке.

Получить байты в "UTF-16BE" можно так:

```
byte[] bytes="новая строка".getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

> Если вывести байты, как Вы предложили byte[] bytes="новая строка".getBytes("UTF-8"), то там первый байт равен -48, а не 61.

Кодировка UTF-8, как указано ранее беззнаковые (от 0 до 255) байты: 208 и 189. Знаковые байты, соответственно, -48 и -67.

Comment: Разве `UTF-8` выдает байты, эквивалентные юникодовскому представлению? Я знаю, что char выдает кодепойнты юникода. Если вывести `System.out.println((byte)'н')`, то это будет равно 61. Если вывести байты, как Вы предложили `byte[] bytes="новая строка".getBytes("UTF-8")`, то там первый байт равен -48, а не 61. Почему байты не совпадают?

Comment: @Dmitry Не хватило комментария, чтобы ответить. Обновил ответ, посмотрите.